# Web интерфейс Python3 (py-postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

Как лучше сделать веб интерфейс через Python3 (py-postgresql) к PostgreSQL?

Comment: Руками должно получиться неплохо!

Comment: А если ещё и голову приложить...

    Тут опять пошла морока про коварный зарубеж
    (В.С. Высоцкий)

@integr1 а вообще web-средств для python очень много, и однозначно "как лучше" Вам вряд ли кто может сказать.

Comment: Здесь конкретно py-postgresql (Python 3.3)

Comment: "Как мне лучше обустроить Россию? Здесь конкретно ВВП 45 трлн (рублей)."

Comment: Наш ответ Fike.
Нам нравится эта работа — называть вещи своими именами. К.Маркс
Д б.

Answer (score 1):

Для веб-разработки на Python существует множество средств. От разработки на чистом WSGI ([раз](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [два](http://maluke.com/old/webdev)) до использования фреймворков вроде Flask ([раз](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [два](http://exploreflask.com/)), [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) и [множества других](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). Выбирайте на ваш вкус.

Comment: Django использует psycopg2 ,а мне нужен фреймворк,который использует
py-postgresql